# How to get value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have this array

```
{
  "findCompletedItemsResponse": [
    {
      "ack": [
        "Success"
      ],
      "version": [
        "1.13.0"
      ],
      "timestamp": [
        "2018-12-16T18:27:26.221Z"
      ],
      "searchResult": [
        {
          "@count": "3",
          "item": [
            {
              "itemId": [
                "263933812890"
              ],... continue
```

I am using this code to get "itemId"

```
for( $i = 0; $i<5; $i++ ) {

    echo $itemid = $data2['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['item'][$i]['itemId'];

}
```

But I am not able to get "itemId". How can I get itemId from this array.

It's also displaying a notice "Undefined index: searchResult"

Comment: Or is it `$data2['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['item'][$i]['itemId'][0]` as `itemId` seems to be an array.

Comment: Although if you give us a valid JSON String we can actually test something before answering

Comment: Its also displaying a notice "Undefined index: searchResult"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `findCompletedItemsResponse` key You have simple array with numeric indexes, same for `searchResult`, so assuming that they both only contains one element:

```
$data2['findCompletedItemsResponse'][0]['searchResult'][0]['item'][$i]['itemId'];
```

Comment: Well, `itemId` is also an array, if You want to get `"263933812890"` from the example it will be `...['itemId'][0];`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is JSON response, you probably need to json decode it:

```
json_decode($data2, true);
```

see if this helps

Comment: I am already using this @$json2 = file_get_contents($myurl);
                            $data2 = json_decode($json2, TRUE);